# How do I connect to MySQL when it's setting behind 2 layers of ssh?

Tags: mysql, ssh, port-forwarding

I have a MySQL server sitting behind a bastion server that I wish to connect to from my local machine.

Ideally I want to port-forward the MySQL port (3316 in this case) to a local port on my machine.

I've tried plink -ssh -L 3306:my.sql.ip.address:3316 my.bastion.server
,but this is not working.

I've got one ssh login for the bastion server and another login for the machine mysql server is running on.

Comment: > I've tried plink -ssh -L 3306:my.sql.ip.address:3316 my.bastion.server ,but this is not working.

Can you elaborate on what is not working? What error messages do you receive?

Answer (score 2):

You can double-chain SSH port forwards, bit a slightly easier method is to set up a "proxy" config in `.ssh/config`:

```
Host *%proxy
    ProxyCommand ssh proxy-user@proxy.host "nc -w1 $(echo %h | cut -d%% -f1) 22"
    ForwardAgent yes
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

Then use `ssh -L 3306:127.0.0.1:3316 final-user@final.host%proxy` to bring up the seesion.

I use this all the time, although normally with dyanamic port forwards (`-D 1080`) to get to management modules of hosts behind overly restrictive firewalls.

Comment: is it possible to achieve this without any possible intervention on the bastion server? i.e. admin will not configure the proxy on the bastion. Thanks

Comment: No intervention is needed. The config is in your ~/.ssh